# Cannot center Drawing Canvases in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I create a lot of Drawing Canvas objects to host diagrams, most being less wide than the page width. The default centering option of Microsoft Word do not seem to work with these objects at all. Is this even possible to do? I am using Microsoft Word 2016.

Comment: Are you talking about centering the Canvas object itself on the page, or the objects within the Canvas object? If it is the objects within the Canvas object, you could hack something together with VBA and the Top and Left properties of the shapes of the objects and the canvas.

Comment: [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-drawing-to-a-document-348a8390-c32e-43d0-942c-b20ad11dea6f) suggests there is a native way to align shapes within a Canvas under Format | Arrange.

Comment: David, I'd like to center the canvas object itself on the page, irrespective of its content. I find it very strange that this simple operation can't be done...

Comment: The Canvas object itself can be centered on the page the same as a Picture object. By default, it is formatted to be `In Line With Text` and it has the normal Alignment options disabled.

Comment: David, for a Picture object I can go to the Home ribbon, Paragraph section and center-align. For the Canvas object, such option is disabled, even if I choose other layout options than the default  "In line with text".

Comment: Have you tried the Format ribbon, Arrange section, and Position in Middle Center with Square Text Wrapping?

Comment: I didn't notice that option, thanks! It effectively centers the canvas object, but it also moves the object itself around, depending on the text paragraphs, which is odd... For example, I have a title, some text, the canvas and some text. It seems like I can't just center the canvas there, but it wants to move it either above the title, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Once your canvas is prepared, move the cursor to the left of the canvas and left-click.  A gray transparent shade will appear over the canvas.  The canvas now can be centered either by pressing Crtl-E or selecting the Home tab and Center button in the Paragraph section.